# what is happening in following code

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Could any one tell me what is happening in following code? I'm trying to work through a tutorial and I'm getting a bit lost.

I'm not sure how the following function could be called, or how to set the parameters (e.g. `if brng =45 and dist=1`.

```
LatLon.prototype.destinationPoint = function(brng, dist) {

    dist = typeof(dist)=='number' ? dist : typeof(dist)=='string' && dist.trim()!='' ? +dist :  NaN;

    dist = dist/this._radius;  // convert dist to angular distance in radians

    brng = brng.toRad();  // 

    var lat1 = this._lat.toRad(), lon1 = this._lon.toRad();

    var lat2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(lat1)*Math.cos(dist) + 
                            Math.cos(lat1)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(brng) );

    var lon2 = lon1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(dist)*Math.cos(lat1),  
                                   Math.cos(dist)-Math.sin(lat1)*Math.sin(lat2));

    lon2 = (lon2+3*Math.PI)%(2*Math.PI) - Math.PI;  // normalise to -180...+180

    return new LatLon(lat2.toDeg(), lon2.toDeg());

}
```

This code can be found at following page http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I see a whole load of horrible variable name choices and general unreadable code.

Comment: What did you try? How about `destinationPoint(45, 1)`?

Comment: How about that... Really, this is a no-brainer. @Shaheryar, you _really_ need to just try things, instead of expecting us to baby sit you through typing every character.

Comment: @JamWaffles I wouldnt have ask you If I myself knew what is happeing in the following code, I As a reference given a link to the website where I got this code from. what this code do is that if you give coordinates of start point along with bearing and distance it would give you coordinates of end point. but I dun know how this code works.

Comment: What do you mean by 'what is happening in the following code' ? You need to add some context to this question, or it will very likely be closed.

Comment: @JamWaffles I come here only when I dont get an answer my self, I been trying this this for many hours now, but no result :(

Comment: @Tim Post I got this code from following site http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html In the description of this code it says that if you give coordinates of start point along with bearing and distance it would give you coordinates of end point. but I dun know how this code works.

Comment: I've edited your question, please try and edit the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

don't know if you ever before coded JS but you have to create a function which will represent you class...

```
function LatLon(lat, lon, rad) {
```

if you wrote this you can invoke this "constructor" by typing

```
var myLatLon = new LatLon(lat, lon, rad)
```

plus the same from before!

Answer (score 0):

You can call it this way

```
var myLatLon = new LatLon();
maLatLon.destinationPoint(45, 1);
```

have you read this!?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_circle

do you want to know what each line does or do want to know whats the purpose of the calculation is ?

Comment: thankyou. What I was looking for is what you replied.

Comment: one more thing I tried  to run  this code but it is just not working

Comment: well .. is this code a snipped you posted a function from a whole class !? if not then you can't call it this way because you have to write the object first!

could you post all the code you have!?

Comment: @ I have copied it from following web site http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: I have copied it from following web site movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html open it and search for followin "Returns the destination point from this point having travelled the given distance (in km) on the" it would take you to the exact code....if you would help me with this I would say thank :)

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html

Comment: so ... if you scroll up a bit .. to the start of the script you will see following lines starting with ... 

    function LatLon(lat, lon, rad) {

Comment: Thankks..... I m sure it would solve my problem now.. I am newbie to javascript and creating an application first time  using all this stuff.... you on yahoo or msn or gmail just in case if i need you help :)

Comment: so as now you know the whole scenario would I call this function as follow <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="lat1" VALUE=""><P>
 <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="lon1" VALUE=""><P>
 <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="brng" VALUE=""><P>
 <INPUT TYPE="text" NAME="dist" VALUE=""><P>
 <script>
 var myLatLon = new LatLon();
 maLatLon.destinationPoint(brng, dist);
 </script>